# (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I see the db file created in my dir but I can't insert into it. My question is very basic can someone please spot the obvious?

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import models

DB_PATH = 'sqlite:////home/ali/test.db'
engine = create_engine(DB_PATH, echo=True)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

### Insert data into ProductionRun table ###
prod_run = models.ProductionRun(instance_id=df.instance_id.iloc[0], name=df.profile_name.iloc[0], host=df.host_box.iloc[0], default_config={})

session.add(prod_run)
session.commit()
```

here is the error that I see

```
OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: ProductionRun
[SQL: INSERT INTO "ProductionRun" (instance_id, name, host, default_config) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: (1, 'Apple', 'host1', '{}')]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/e3q8)
```

Here is ProductionRun in `models.py`

```
class ProductionRun(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'ProductionRun'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    instance_id = Column(Integer, nullable=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    host = Column(String, nullable=False)
    default_config = Column(JSON, nullable=False)

    status_change = relationship('ProductionRunStatusChange', back_populates='production_run')
```

Comment: If you run `sqlite3 test.db` in the terminal and then do a `SELECT * FROM ProductionRun` does it actually show you some result?

Comment: You have to create the table before inserting into it. `sqlalchemy.MetaData().create_all()`

Comment: @jordanm `session.commit()` creates the db implicitly.

Comment: @FedericoBaù I get a `InvalidRequestError: Class <class 'models.ProductionRun'> does not have a __table__ or __tablename__ specified and does not inherit from an existing table-mapped class.` if I remove __tablename__. Also, querying it from test.db returns nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because is Sqlite  the table classes needs to happen before the DB is created.

```py
DB_PATH = 'sqlite:////home/ali/test.db'
engine = create_engine(DB_PATH, echo=True)
BASE.metadata.create_all(engine)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
```

### Reference of other Stack Overflow Answer

- [sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61678766/sqlalchemy-exc-operationalerror-sqlite3-operationalerror-no-such-table-items/61694048#61694048)
- [Getting empty sqlite DB and “(sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table:..:” when trying to add item](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50353577/13903942)

### Documentation

- [Accessing the MetaData](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/declarative/basic_use.html#accessing-the-metadata)